# How do I specify which columns to print to a text file using Python?

Tags: python

Here's an example of my current output:

> ['5216', 'SMITH', 'VICTORIA', 'F', '2009-12-19']

This is my code:

```
users1 = open('users1.txt','w')

with open('users.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

    for line in data:
        words = str(line.split())
        #print words
        f.seek(0)
        users1.write(words)
```

I would like to read in `users.txt` and separate the information to send it to `users1` and another text file I'll call `users2`. (Keep in mind this is a hypothetical situation and that I acknowledge it would not make sense to separate this information like I'm suggesting below.)

*Is it possible to identify specific columns I'd like to insert into each text file?*

For example, if I wanted `users1.txt` to contain, using my sample output from above, `['5216','2009-12-19']` and `users2.txt` to contain `['SMITH','VICTORIA']`, what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [use slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/190597) to select items from the list. For example,

```
In [219]: words = ['5216', 'SMITH', 'VICTORIA', 'F', '2009-12-19']

In [220]: [words[0], words[-1]]
Out[220]: ['5216', '2009-12-19']

In [221]: words[1:3]
Out[221]: ['SMITH', 'VICTORIA']
```

---

```
with open('users.txt', 'r') as f,\
     open('users1.txt','w') as users1,\
     open('users2.txt','w') as users2:
    for line in f:
        words = line.split()
        users1.write(str([words[0], words[-1]])
        users2.write(str(words[1:3])
```

Including the brackets `[]` in the output is non-standard. 
For portability, and proper handling of quoted strings and strings containing the comma delimiter, you would be better off using the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import csv
with open('users.txt', 'rb') as f,\
     open('users1.txt','wb') as users1,\
     open('users2.txt','wb') as users2:
    writer1 = csv.writer(users1, delimiter=',')
    writer2 = csv.writer(users2, delimiter=',')     
    for line in f:
        words = line.split()
        writer1.writerow([words[0], words[-1]])
        writer2.writerow(words[1:3])
```

Answer (score 1):

I (too) suggest you use the`csv`module. However by using its`DictReader`and`DictWriter`you can assign field names to the each column and use them to easily specify which ones you want to go into which output file. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
import csv

users_fieldnames = 'ID', 'LAST', 'FIRST', 'SEX', 'DATE'  # input file field names
users1_fieldnames = 'ID', 'DATE'     # fields to go into users1 output file
users2_fieldnames = 'LAST', 'FIRST'  # fields to go into users2 output file

with open('users.txt', 'rb') as inf:
    csvreader = csv.DictReader(inf, fieldnames=users_fieldnames, delimiter=' ')

    with open('users1.txt', 'wb') as outf1, open('users2.txt', 'wb') as outf2:
        csvwriter1 = csv.DictWriter(outf1, fieldnames=users1_fieldnames,
                                    extrasaction='ignore', delimiter=' ')
        csvwriter2 = csv.DictWriter(outf2, fieldnames=users2_fieldnames,
                                    extrasaction='ignore', delimiter=' ')
        for row in csvreader:
            csvwriter1.writerow(row)   # writes data for only user1_fieldnames
            csvwriter2.writerow(row)   # writes data for only user2_fieldnames
```

Only the columns specified in the constructor calls to`csv.DictWriter()`will be written to the output file by the corresponding`writerow()`method call.

Answer (score 0):

If your data has the same structure for all entries you can make use of pandas and numpy packages.
A lot of flexibility for selecting whatever columns you need.